# Linking plots (box select, lasso etc) in Bokeh generated in a loop

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plotting some data using bokeh using a for loop to iterate over my columns in the dataframe. For some reason the box select and lasso tools which I have managed to have as linked in plots explicitly plotted (i.e. not generated with a for loop) does not seem to work now.

Do I need to increment some bokeh function within the for loop?

```
#example dataframe
array = {'variable': ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'], 
      'var1': [np.random.rand(10)],
     'var2': [np.random.rand(10)],
     'var3': [np.random.rand(10)],
     'var4': [np.random.rand(10)]}

cols = ['var1',
       'var2',
        'var3',
        'var4']

df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = cols)


w = 500
h = 400

#collect plots in a list (start with an empty)
plots = []

#iterate over the columns in the dataframe
# specify the tools in TOOLS
#add additional lines to show tolerance bands etc

for c in df[cols]:
    source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = df.index, y = df[c]))
    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select,lasso_select"

    f = figure(tools = TOOLS, width = w, plot_height = h, title = c + ' Run Chart', 
        x_axis_label = 'Run ID', y_axis_label = c)
    f.line('x', 'y', source = source, name = 'data')
    f.triangle('x', 'y', source = source)

    #data mean line
    f.line(df.index, df[c].mean(), color = 'orange')

    #tolerance lines
    f.line (df.index, df[c + 'USL'][0], color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', line_width = 2)
    f.line (df.index, df[c + 'LSL'][0], color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', line_width = 2)

#append the new plot in this loop to the existing list of plots       
    plots.append(f)

#link all the x_ranges    
for i in plots:
    i.x_range = plots[0].x_range

#plot    
p = gridplot(plots, ncols = 2)
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

I expect to produce plots which are linked and allow me to box or lasso select some points on one chart and for them to be highlighted on the others. However, the plots only let me select on one plot with no linked behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

This may seem a bit of a noob problem, but I am sure someone else will come across this, so here is the answer!!!

Bokeh works by referring to a datasource object (the columndatasource object). You can pass your dataframe completely into this and then call explicit x and y values within the glyph creation (e.g. my f.line, f.triangle etc).

So I moved the 'source' outside of the loop to prevent it being reset each iteration and just passed my df to it. I then within the loop, call the iteration index + descriptor string (USL, LSL, mean) for the y values and the 'index' for my x values.

I add a box select tool explicitly with a 'name' defined so that when the box selects, it only selects those glyphs that I want it to select (i.e. don't want it to select my constant value mean and spec limit lines).

Also, be careful that if you want to output to a html or something, that you probably will need to supress your in-notebook output as bokeh does not like having duplicate plots open. I have not included my html output solution here.

In terms of adding linked lasso objects for loop generated plots, I could only find an explicit box select tool generator so not sure this is possible.

So here it is:

```
#keep the source out of the loop to stop it resetting every time
Source = ColumnDataSource(df)


for c in cols:

    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

    f = figure(tools = TOOLS, width = w, plot_height = h, title = c + ' Run Chart', 
        x_axis_label = 'Run ID', y_axis_label = c)
    f.line(x = 'index', y = c , source = Source, name = 'data')
    f.triangle(x = 'index',  y = c, source = Source, name = 'data')

    #data mean line
    f.line(x = 'index', y = c + '_mean', source = Source, color = 'orange')

    #tolerance lines
    f.line (x = 'index', y = c + 'USL', color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', line_width = 2, source = Source)
    f.line (x = 'index', y = c + 'LSL', color = 'red', line_dash = 'dashed', line_width = 2, source = Source)

    # Add BoxSelect tool - this allows points on one plot to be highligted on all linked plots.  Note only the delta info
    # is linked using name='data'.  Again names can be used to ensure only the relevant glyphs are highlighted.
    bxselect1 = BoxSelectTool(renderers=f.select(name='data'))
    f.add_tools(bxselect1)

    plots.append(f)

#tie the x_ranges together so that panning is linked between plots    
for i in plots:
    i.x_range = plots[0].x_range

forp = gridplot(plots, ncols = 2)
show(forp)
```